# "zsh: command not found: fvm" When I open my Flutter project in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-support-library, zshrc

I've added these to my .zshrc file

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/.pub-cache/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/fvm/default/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin"
```

Flutter and fvm seem to work fine when I work in Terminal.
But once I create a new project and I use the terminal in Android Studio, I cant find the commands.

```
➜  flutter_fvm_stable echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin:/Users/{Username}/flutter_fvm_stable/.pub-cache/bin:/Users/{Username}/flutter_fvm_stable/fvm/default/bin:/Users/{Username}/flutter_fvm_stable/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin


➜  flutter_fvm_stable fvm doctor
zsh: command not found: fvm
```

I managed to fix this issue for the flutter command:

```
➜  flutter_fvm_stable exexport PATH="/Users/{Username}/flutter/bin:$PATH" 
➜  flutter_fvm_stable flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-BE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
...
```

But when I try it with the fvm path, I still get nothing..

```
➜  flutter_fvm_stable exexport PATH="/Users/{Username}/fvm/default/bin:$PATH" 
➜  flutter_fvm_stable fvm doctor
zsh: command not found: fvm
```

I've tried running

```
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

But then I get

```
Warning: Pub installs executables into $HOME/.pub-cache/bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding this to your shell's config file (.bashrc, .bash_profile, etc.):

  export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
```

While I already have this line in my .zshrc file

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/.pub-cache/bin"
```

Thank you so much for trying to help me out!

Answer (score 1):

while using brew to install fvm is a valid approach it's not a direct solution to the initial question.

the script below fixes the issue

```bash
echo 'export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/fvm/default/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc && \
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved since I used this code in Terminal outside of Android Studio:

```
brew tap leoafarias/fvm
brew install fvm
```

Answer (score -1):

I had installed from homebrew package manager and I had to add this path

`/opt/homebrew/bin/`

to my ~/.zshrc profile

in order to make fvm work in any terminal.